# Oracle APEX 5.0 multiple spaces show as single space in IR

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report against a database table.  One column contains multiple spaces in the middle of the string.  The report is masking the multiple spaces and showing as only a single space.  I want to show the exact table column value on the report.

I tried changing the column attributes from "Display as Text (escape special characters)" to "Standard Report Column" and nothing changed.  I don't see any other APEX column attributes that will force the spaces to show.  Any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column properties:

- navigate to "file name" column's property palette (right hand side of the screen)
- scroll down to **static ID** and name it somehow (for example, `col_with_spaces`)

Page properties:

- go to page's property palette
- scroll down to **CSS** and put this into the **Inline** CSS:

  ```
  .a-IRR-table tr td[headers*="col_with_spaces"]
  {
      white-space: pre;
  }
  ```
- run the page; result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, that worked.  I also stumbled across another solution where I just put <div><PRE>#FILE_NAME#</PRE></div> in the HTML Expression box for that particular column.

Comment: but now I found another page where the FILE_NAME is just an item on a page, not a report.  I can't figure out how to apply your solution to that item.  My solution seems to add a line feed to this result.

Comment: Then you may be able to adjust the selector #P1_FILE_NAME {white-space:pre;}

Comment: Thanks @Scott.  Under the "HTML Form Element Attributes" box, I added: style="white-space: pre", and this worked.